# Merge two tables and aggregate

Tags: r

I have two tables name and grades which looks like:

table:name

```
Male   Female

Sam    Tina
       Anna
```

table:grades

```
Class  Name  Grades
A      Sam   5
B      Sam   5
A      Tina  5
B      Tina  5
C      Tina  5
A      Anna  5
```

After merging the new table should looks like:

```
Class Gender Grades
A     Male   5
B     Male   5
A     Female 10
B     Female 5
C     Female 5
```

I have tried groupby, merge, but it always give me a wrong table.
Is there any function that I can use to get the right table? Thanks!!

Comment: Convert "name" to long format - search wide-to-long. Then merge as usual, then aggregate on Gender.

Answer (score 3):

Convert *name* dataframe to long format using *stack*. Then *merge* as usual, then aggregate on **Gender** and **Class**:

```
aggregate(Grades ~ Class + ind,
          merge(grades, na.omit(stack(name)), by.x = "Name", by.y = "values"), sum)
#   Class    ind Grades
# 1     A   Male      5
# 2     B   Male      5
# 3     A Female     10
# 4     B Female      5
# 5     C Female      5

#data
name <- read.table(text = "
Male Female
Sam Tina
NA Anna", header = TRUE)

grades <- read.table(text = "
Class  Name  Grades
A      Sam   5
B      Sam   5
A      Tina  5
B      Tina  5
C      Tina  5
A      Anna  5", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Much nicer than mine! Thanks for that one :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution with no dependencies looks like this::

Your data might look like this:

```
names <- data.frame(gender = c("Male", "Female", "Female"),
                    name = c("Sam", "Tina", "Anna"))

grades <- data.frame(class = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A"),
                     name =  c("Sam", "Sam", "Tina", "Tina", "Tina", "Anna"),
                     grades = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5))
```

Then you can match the gender variable into the grades `data.frame` and summarize the grades by class and gender:

```
## Match the gender variable into your dataframe with grades
grades$gender <- names$gender[match(grades$name, names$name)]

## summarize grades by class and gender
result <- tapply(grades$grades, list(grades$class, grades$gender), sum)
```

Finally you will want to reshape to long and cleanup the `data.frame` a little:

```
## reshape to long and cleanup
result <- as.data.frame(result)
result$class <- rownames(result)
result <- reshape(result,
                  direction = "long",
                  varying = list(1:2),
                  timevar = "gender",
                  v.names = "grades")
result <- result[, c("class", "gender", "grades")]
```

You should get this:

```
> result
class gender grades
1.1     A      1     10
2.1     B      1      5
3.1     C      1      5
1.2     A      2      5
2.2     B      2      5
3.2     C      2     NA
```

Comment: Today I learned: reshape is part of stats package? :O

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
name %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = 'Gender') %>% distinct() %>% 
   inner_join(grades, by = c('value' = 'Name')) %>% select(Class, Gender, Grades) %>% 
   group_by(Class, Gender) %>% summarise(Grades = sum(Grades))
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'Class' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   Class [3]
  Class Gender Grades
  <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
1 A     Female     10
2 A     Male        5
3 B     Female      5
4 B     Male        5
5 C     Female      5
```

Data used:

```
name
  Male Female
1  Sam   Tina
2  Sam   Anna
grades
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Class Name  Grades
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
1 A     Sam        5
2 B     Sam        5
3 A     Tina       5
4 B     Tina       5
5 C     Tina       5
6 A     Anna       5
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! The code works perfecly fine till "group_by", after group_by and summarise, the output turns to NA with only one variable :(

Comment: @Jasper, try sum(Grades, na.rm = TRUE)

Comment: It works, thank you! One more question, do you know how to add suffix to values (for example A, B,C in class column) by str_ function?

Comment: @Jasper, just add  `%>% mutate(Class = str_c(Class, '_suffix'))` at the end after the summarise, you can replace '_suffix' in str_c with whatever you want.